# Finding 2D points reachable with short intermediate hops

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, path-finding, adjacency-list

I have a list `allNodes` of around 60,000 nodes that correspond to 2D points. I'm constructing an adjacency list like

```
for(i in allNodes)
  for(j in allNodes)
    if(distance(i, j) <= 10) addEdge between i and j
```

and then performing a depth-first search from a set of `sourceNodes` to find the set of nodes reachable from `sourceNodes`. How can I make this faster than quadratic? I'm using C++.

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat if distance between two nodes is less than or equal to 10, they make an edge

Comment: How is distance defined?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Nodes are given as a struct which has an array of Pos[2] as is a 2d coordinate. I am making all my data structures as a pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binning approach suggested by David Eisenstat's answer works if you expect points to be homogeneously distributed, which is not a property you specified about your data. Additionally, as noted, the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) still requires local search on the induced graph to ensure that all nodes within the specified distance are found.

One way to get guaranteed performance is with a [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). You can build one in *O(2n log n)* time (or faster if you don't care as much about guarantees and use randomization) and use it for performing range searches with a total time of *O(2n√n)*.

It's unclear to me whether the Delaunay triangulation or the kd-tree would be faster in practice, but it seems to me that finding and using an appropriate kd-tree library would be a fast and simple solution, if you are worried about development time.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The easy approach is to divide the plane into d-by-d where d > 10 bins and put each point in the bin indexed by floor(x/d), floor(y/d). Then, instead of iterating over all pairs of points,

```
for bin1 in bins:
   for i in bin1:
      for bin2 in bins neighboring bin in nine directions (including bin):
         for j in bin2:
            if(distance(i, j) <= 10) addEdge between i and j
```

This will make things faster if the points are well spread, but the worst case is still quadratic.

For a guaranteed O(n log n)-time algorithm, compute the Delaunay triangulation and throw away the edges longer than 10. This may remove some direct connections between nodes at distance less than or equal to 10, but they will still be connected indirectly.

Comment: I upvoted your solution but my reputation is not big enough to make it count.